# Setup Schema.org application to host an extension

Tags: schema.org

I try to host my extension of schema.org with schema.org application https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg.
But I can't figure where I should placed my rdfa file to achieve this.

Will be cool to have ability to show my extension terms separetely like it's done for bib extension, please see image

http://soil.by/screen/upload/screen_006.jpg

Comment: Did you try something? Each extension seems to have a folder in `/data/ext`, which contains the RDFa file(s) and examples.

Comment: Yes, I try to add directory for my extension, but it seems that application didn't read it.
I found an workaround solution by modification Python code, will provide as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution to place your extension like an schema.org hosted extension. It solve a problem, but have some inconvience.

To your extension has been read you need add additional element to 
sdoapp.py

```
ENABLED_EXTENSIONS = [ 'auto', 'bib', '%YOUR_EXT_NAME%' ]
ALL_LAYERS = [ 'core', 'auto', 'bib', '%YOUR_EXT_NAME%']
```

After that you can place your rdfa into data/ext/%YOUR_EXT_NAME%/any_file_name.rdfa

RDFa should describe terms with schema:isPartOf property in this way

```
<div typeof="rdfs:Class" resource="http://schema.org/AnEntity">
    <link property="http://schema.org/isPartOf" href="http://%YOUR_EXT_NAME%.schema.org"/>
</div>
```

The main disadvantage is that your terms now will be accessible via additional subdomain.

For example you host your extension under http://schema.example.com

Your terms will be accessiable under

http://%YOUR_EXT_NAME%.schema.example.com/AnEntity

and it's not very good

Comment: It will be cool to see terms under http://schema.example.com/AnEntity but without modification of schema.org core rdfa and with ability to filter custom terms, like it works for hosted extension.